# What is the relation to the order of which memory is stored

Tags: assembly, memory, webassembly

I have been trying and failing to understand [calculating] offsets in memory management.

The reason I want to do this is because I need to pass an array to WASM to subtract it, which is not possible due to WASM having only number types.
Someone told me to achieve this I would have to calculate offset and pass in a typed array via JavaScript.

I understand that offsets are just what they sound like - the distance from the location of one address to another, but I don't exactly know how to calculate it. The resources I have found are good at explaining what it is, but I can't, for the life of me, find out the relation between the memory addresses to calculate offset.

I don't understand how to calculate offset, because I don't exactly know the order of memory stored (E.g: Is memory stored in climbing order like 0x001, 0x002, 0x003).

So, to answer the question about calculating offset, I have to first answer the main question - *what is relation to the order of which memory is stored*.

This is all confusing to me because I come from a high-level language environment where you don't typically work with offsets and memory addresses.

Resources I used to [try to] help me on this subject:

- [http://users.cs.fiu.edu/~downeyt/cda4101/jumpoff.html](http://users.cs.fiu.edu/%7Edowneyt/cda4101/jumpoff.html)
- https://datacadamia.com/computer/memory/segment/offset
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_(computer_science)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the simplest level, yes, memory is like a giant array whose elements are bytes.
(Assuming a normal modern computer architecture, one that's byte-addressable not word, flat memory model, etc.)

A wider access can load multiple bytes at once, as an integer (or as an FP double like JavaScript numbers that aren't in a TypedArray).

An array is just a range of addresses.  (Or a start address and a length, or start and end addresses).  Offsets into an array are used (in real CPU assembly) by accessing "the memory" at an address of start + offset, where `start` is the address of the array's first element.  e.g. in x86-64 assembly, `mov eax, [rdi + rsi*4]` / `ret` implements the C function

```
int32_t idx_arr(int32_t *array_start, size_t index) {
    return array_start[index];        // mov eax, [rdi + rsi*4]
}
```

Notice that in asm, you have to manually scale the index by the element-size to get an offset in bytes.

Fun fact, `return *(array_start+index);` is exactly identical because C defines the [] operator in terms of pointer math.  And normally you'd just call your pointer arg `array`; I used `array_start` to make the point that in assembly, you normally just get a pointer to the start, and sometimes the length or end_ptr as a separate arg so you can loop over it.

An array object or slice that knows its own length is a high-level construct, something you could implement with a data structure containing 2 pointers.

I don't know how much of this applies to *Web* Assembly, sorry; there you might actually get a TypedArray that can still do bounds-checking to stop you from writing or reading outside the array boundaries.  In asm for real CPUs (or in C), nothing prevents that if you don't manually check the `index` against a known length, or prove that it will be in bounds based on loop logic or known contents of where you got the index from.

Comment: Huh, I'll have to read that a bit more. So, offset in a way *is* calculated in increasing or decreasing size, but how much is what I'm saying. Is it +1 every memory address, +2, e.t.c? Calculating offset is easy, but I can't do it without knowledge of how the memory is stored.

Comment: @Reality: yes, the first byte of memory has address 0, the next has address 1, and so on.  (Within the virtual address space of your process, normally you wouldn't actually have address 0 mapped.)  But anyway yes, adjacent bytes are 1 address apart.  (That's what being an array of bytes implies).  Adjacent 4-byte int32s are 4 addresses apart, that's why you scale the C index by 4 = sizeof(int32_t) when implementing in x86 asm.  WASM might do the scaling for you, I don't know, but if so then you'd just be doing array indexing like in JavaScript.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. It also depends on the size of the bytes as well, that makes sense (since it stores bytes). Ok, I'm still going to have to experiment a bit, but at least I know a bit more on what I'm doing. Thanks!